# Is there any way to show the jquery datepicker for only a single month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I show the datepicker or how can I restrict it to show only for a specified month? Lets say only for November or February.

Comment: what did you find when you searched?

Comment: Found nothing @mitchwheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default month using `defaultDate`. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$(function() {
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(1);  //Defalt month feburary
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       defaultDate: d
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zg8Le/242/)**

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I was thinking there should be a setMonth and setYear method. But wasn't aware of it. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/tx32r7y7/

Answer (score 1):

Here u can see only one month in JQuery datepicker:

Following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
 $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Show different options here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Can I see month of February by default? And in another instance of it I would like to see August only.